# Automatic dates in R markdown beamer

Tags: r, markdown, beamer

I am using R Markdown to produce a Beamer presentation. How can I put the date that authomatically updates his values? The current setting are below:

```
title: "MyTitle"
author: "MyName"
date: "19th April 2015"
 output:
 beamer_presentation:
 incremental: no
 keep_tex: yes
 toc: yes
ioslides_presentation:
incremental: yes
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{url}
 bibliography: myBib.bib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\today`, I think it should work but only if your output is PDF (which uses LaTeX) or a Beamer presentation.